# Use of unresolved identifier 'Parse'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm following the following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-1-of-3-f50842aa95a) trying to set up a basic Swift app with Parse. After following all the steps in part one I get the following error in AppDelegate.swift and running the application fails:

[image]

I've used my real application ID and client key, and not "xxxyyyyzzzz" and "aaaabbbbcccc".

I've linked all the frameworks as instructed:

[image]

I've also added a bridging header file with the appropriate name:

[image]

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `import Parse` after your `import UIKit`